# Built-in Port forwarding > Vagrant package can't find Vagrantfile.pkg

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, puppet, virtualization

Following the documentation for vagrant vbox packaging [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/packaging.html).
I am attempting to package a virtual box with port forwarding auto-configured by including an auxiliary vagrant file Vagrantfile.pkg thusly:

`vagrant package dev --output mybox.box --vagrantfile Vagrantfile.pkg`

And I get the following error:

`Package include file doesn't exist: Vagrantfile.pkg`

I have tried putting this in the project root (where the main vagrantfile is), in the VM shared folder, and a few other places, all with the same error.

My host environment is Windows 7, which I suspect is the source of this issue.

Has anyone succeeded at packaging a vagrant file for this purpose?

Here is the content of Vagrantfile.pkg for reference, not that it should affect this bug.

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.host_name = 'dev.local'
  config.vm.network :hostonly, '192.168.33.35'
  config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a guess, the following appears to have worked:

`vagrant package dev --output mybox.box --vagrantfile ../Vagrantfile.pkg`